# Create a javascript msgbox (YES/NO) and get results in code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to create a (yes/no) javascript messagebox from code-behind, and also retrieve the return values?

I would like to set the content of a session object based on the client Yes/No.

The idea is to use this approach for redirecting iphone clients from my default web page.

> "Do you want to go the iphone version of this site?"
>
> --YES Redirect to "iphone" default page, and set a session object to avoid asking this question again if default page is requested again
>   within the lifespan of the session object.
>
> --NO Set a session object to avoid asking this question again if default page is requested again within the lifespan of the session
>   object.

Comment: what about [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.confirm)? `confirm("Do you want to go the iphone version of this site?")`

Comment: What about the so famous AJAX?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just display the message and set an appropiate cookie. Then make your server-side react to the cookie and render the selected version of the site.

http://www.htmlite.com/JS006.php - Javascript Confirm popup

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp - Javascript cookies

Answer (score 1):

Or you could stash the value in a hidden field and read it on the server side.

** EDIT **

OP Comment:

> I would like to set the content of a session object based on the client Yes/No.

Either way you look at it, if he wants to set this value in session, he has to go back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

In Code behind on FormLoad or wherever it best suits your needs, you would just have to set your button's OnClientClick as follows:

```
    button.OnClientClick = "IphoneVersion()";
```

In Markup create a function in javascript as follows:

```
function IphoneVersion() {
        if (confirm('Do you want to go the iphone version of this site?')) {
            //set hidden value here            }
        else { //don't set hidden value }
    }
```

You can set your Hidden control value to yes/no text and refer to it behind code or you can redirect in the function itself.
That will do it!

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
confirmSomething = function(){        
    __doPostBack("<%=Button1.ClientID%>", confirm("Are you sure?")); 
}

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="confirmSomething();" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{   
    bool conf = bool.Parse(eventArgument);
}
```

Comment: Please explain? What's the problem with this approach? Seems a lot better than setting a cookie.